# Disable login via wp-login.php but allow through custom login page

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, wordpress

I have a free custom login/register sidebar widget and I wants that all users must login or register through this custom login widget. So, I tried to disable `wp-login.php` by denying IP address except mine via `.htaccess`.

But, this is not working. When I tried to login (by using proxy) through custom login widget, it simply didn't logged in.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Many thanks in advance.

Note: **This question is related to wordpress login**. I tried to search similar question here but found only one without any solution.